# What functions for recurring payments with different amount?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, recurring-billing

I need someone to point me in the right direction of what is the best Paypal product to use and the associated functions I need to accomplish my project.

I have a site where a user can signup for a internet phone service with a set monthly fee, lets say $200 for 1000 minutes.

The problem I have is that:
1. The first month is pro-rated so the amount may change.
2. If a user of my site goes over their allotted minutes I will charge them an overage fee in their next billing cycle, so the recurring payment may be different also.

From what I read I need to use adaptive payments is this correct, what functions should I use for creating, capturing and receiving payments.

Please help, I'm really in a bind.

Answer (score 1):

There are many products that will do this. Avoid searching for "Recurring Payments" as that is generally used to refer to specific, relatively fixed payment schedules (like subscriptions) that you set up once with the payment partner (PayPal) and they execute the payments on that schedule for you. These schedules can be configured somewhat flexibly (e.g. free or reduced initial payment) but require that you can state the schedule & amounts in advance.

If you have more variable needs to collect payments from your users then you generally manage the timing and amount of the payments yourself; then you just need a mechanism for billing the user, ie a billing agreement.

PayPal products that support some form of billing agreements include PayPal Reference Transactions, PayPal Adaptive Payments, and the PayPal RESTful Payments suite.

Getting into opinion territory here, but of these three I would recommend either Reference Transaction (as the longest-standing, most mature and widely used solution) or the RESTful payments suite (as the latest and greatest solution) over Adaptive.